# Could someone help me understand Room persistence library better?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, dao

I've started making an app for android, and decided to learn more about databases. I think I understand SQL well enough for a simple app. What I'm having trouble with is Room. I've read a lot and watched tutorials but I still cannot quite understand what would be the proper way to implement it. Here's what I gathered. I think that I should have entities, DAOs, databases and repositories.

The idea behind my app is this. I'd have workouts, exercises etc.

Workouts should have exercises.

For now I imagined it to be 2 tables: workout_table, exercise_table

Every Workout and Exercise should have a unique id/primary key ofc

Workout entity would have 2 attributes: workoutId, workoutName

Exercise entity would have 2 attributes: exerciseId, exerciseName

These two tables I plan on connecting with many to many or one to many relation, but that's not the problem I'm having right now.

Now, after making data classes for both these entities, I created a Dao class for each of them.
So, WorkoutDao and Exercise Dao (Because I read that it's a good practice to have one dao per entity). Now what I don't quite get is, many people said online that I should have one database per entity which seems very weird to me. Shouldn't I have one database with all the tables that have any relation to each other. And how do I connect the tables if I have one DAO for each table. Also I'm not quite whether or not should I have one Repository per entity/table or one repository per database.entity.

And one more question about ViewModel combined with Room. I gathered that I should have one ViewModel per Activity that is basically shared between fragments. Lets say I have an activity that has recyclerView with a list of workouts and when I click on any workout in the list I go to another activity which has a recycler view that shows every exercise that the clicked workout has. Would both viewModels instantiate the same database? Because it seems like it's not the best solution. Since workoutViewModel should only have a list of workouts and exerciseViewModel should have a list of exercises (well, exercises of the clicked workout). How would I go about solving that?

Anyhow, sorry if what I wrote is confusing, I'll try to explain it better if it's not understood, I'm still quite new when it comes to kotlin and android studio

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't I have one database with all the tables that have any relation to each other.

Yes.

> These two tables I plan on connecting with many to many or one to many relation, but that's not the problem I'm having right now.

You probably want a many-many i.e. workouts can have a number of exercises and an exercise can have many workouts as parents.

As such you would use a third table for the relationships, that consists of a column for the workout's id and a column for the exercise's id. Such a table has numerous names such as an associative table, reference table ....

> And how do I connect the tables if I have one DAO for each table.
> Multiple Dao's can be defined and accessed.

See the following demonstration (the @Database class **TheDatabase**), in short you just let the @Database class know about them and allow the dao's to be retrieved Room does all the underlying work for you.

---

---

**Demonstration**

Here's an basic working example based upon your description, this also includes both dao's for each entity and also all dao's combined:-

The **Workout** entity (table) :-

```
@Entity
data class Workout(
    @PrimaryKey
    val workoutId: Long? = null,
    val workoutName: String
)
```

The **WorkoutDao** :-

```
@Dao
abstract class WorkoutDao {

    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(workout: Workout): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM workout")
    abstract fun getAllWorkouts(): List<Workout>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM exercise WHERE exerciseId=:exerciseId")
    abstract fun getWorkoutById(exerciseId: Long): Exercise
}
```

- Note rather than being an interface it's an abstract class (which can be beneficial)

The **Exercise** entity (table)

```
@Entity(
    indices = [Index(value = ["exerciseName"],unique = true)] // enforce unique exercise name.
)
data class Exercise(
    @PrimaryKey
    val exerciseId: Long? = null,
    val exerciseName: String
)
```

- Note here we have added a unique index for the exercise name, so the exercise name must be unique (could also be applied to Workout).

The **ExerciseDao**

```
@Dao
abstract class ExerciseDao {
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(exercise: Exercise): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM exercise")
    abstract fun getAllExercises(): List<Exercise>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM exercise WHERE exerciseId=:exerciseId")
    abstract fun getExerciseById(exerciseId: Long): Exercise
}
```

- Note see the equivalent in AllDao (below) as the insert function does not cater for handling duplicate Exercise names (AllDao does, the activity code demonstrates the difference)

As you probably want a many-many relationship the the mapping table **WorkoutExerciseMap** entity (table) :-

```
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["workoutIdMap","exerciseIdMap"], // a combination of  workout/exercise is primary key
    indices = [Index("exerciseIdMap")],  // Room issues warning if not indexed
    foreignKeys = [
        // Foreign keys, each defines a constraint (rule) saying value to be store MUST exist in the parent table
        // i.e. the value to be stored in the workoutIdMap MUST be the id of an existing Workout
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Workout::class, // the entity/table that the FK points to
            parentColumns = ["workoutId"], // the column in the parent table
            childColumns = ["workoutIdMap"], // column in this table where
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE, // if a Workout is deleted then delete the children
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE // if a workoutId is changed then change the children
        ),
        ForeignKey(entity = Exercise::class,parentColumns = ["exerciseId"],childColumns = ["exerciseIdMap"])
    ]
)
data class WorkoutExerciseMap(
    val workoutIdMap: Long,
    val exerciseIdMap: Long
)
```

- see comments that are hopefully helpful

The **WorkoutExerciseMapDao** :-

```
@Dao
abstract class WorkoutExerciseMapDao {
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(workoutExerciseMapDao: WorkoutExerciseMap): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM workoutexercisemap")
    abstract fun getAllWorkoutExerciseMaps(): List<WorkoutExerciseMap>
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM workout")
    abstract fun getAllWorkoutsWithExercises(): List<WorkoutWithExercises>

}
```

- Should getAllWorkoutsWithExercises be here? (rhetorical)
- Is returning the rowid any use after an insert? (rhetorical)
- Would retrieving the mappings be of any use? (rhetorical)

To be able to get Workouts with the related Exercises requires a POJO (not an entity) so **WorkoutWithExercises** :-

```
data class WorkoutWithExercises(
    @Embedded
    val workout: Workout,
    @Relation(
        entity = Exercise::class,
        parentColumn = "workoutId",
        entityColumn = "exerciseId",
        associateBy = Junction(WorkoutExerciseMap::class,parentColumn = "workoutIdMap",entityColumn = "exerciseIdMap")
    )
    val exercises: List<Exercise>
)
```

- @Embedded includes a single Workout
- @Relation will retrieve all related Exercises, via  mapping (associative) table WorkoutExerciseMap

  - if you wanted Exercise's with all the related Workouts, you could have similar POJO with relationships reversed.

Regarding whether or not it's bad/good to have individual Dao's here's **AllDao** with, as the name implies, **ALL** of the dao's in a single class :-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {

    /*
     As exercise has a unique index on exercisename skip if same exercise name is used
     otherwise duplicating name will result in an exception
     */
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(exercise: Exercise): Long
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(workout: Workout): Long
    @Insert
    /*
        not much use (if any) of returning Long as value will be the
        rowid (hidden column).
    */
    abstract fun insert(workoutExerciseMap: WorkoutExerciseMap): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM workout")
    abstract fun getAllWorkouts(): List<Workout>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM workout WHERE workout.workoutId=:workoutId")
    abstract fun getWorkoutById(workoutId: Long): Workout
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Exercise")
    abstract fun getAllExercises(): List<Exercise>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM exercise WHERE exercise.exerciseId=:exerciseId")
    abstract fun getExerciseById(exerciseId: Long): Exercise
    @Query("SELECT * FROM workout")
    @Transaction
    abstract fun getAllWorkoutsWithExercises(): List<WorkoutWithExercises>

}
```

- there are advantages/disadvantages to all-together v separate, it's certainly possible for either and even for All and separate to co-exist (although that would add maintanance complications)

Tying all the components is the @Database class **TheDatabase** :-

```
@Database(entities = [Workout::class,Exercise::class,WorkoutExerciseMap::class],version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getWorkoutDao(): WorkoutDao
    abstract fun getExerciseDao(): ExerciseDao
    abstract fun getWorkoutExerciseMapDao(): WorkoutExerciseMapDao

    /* Versus all in one Dao ???? */
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabaseInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"workoutexercise.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- Note that for convenience/brevity running/testing the above will be done on the main thread.

Actual use of the above is demonstrated via an activity **MainActivity** :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var workoutDao: WorkoutDao
    lateinit var exerciseDao: ExerciseDao
    lateinit var workoutExerciseMapDao: WorkoutExerciseMapDao
    lateinit var allDao: AllDao

    private final var TAG = "WOEINFO"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getDatabaseInstance(this)
        workoutDao = db.getWorkoutDao()
        exerciseDao = db.getExerciseDao()
        workoutExerciseMapDao = db.getWorkoutExerciseMapDao()


        var ex1 = exerciseDao.insert(Exercise(exerciseName = "Exercise1"))
        var ex2 = exerciseDao.insert(Exercise(exerciseName = "Exercise2"))
        var ex3 = exerciseDao.insert(Exercise(exerciseName = "Exercise3"))
        var ex4 = exerciseDao.insert(Exercise(exerciseName =  "Exercise4"))
        var ex5 = exerciseDao.insert(Exercise(exerciseName = "Exercise5"))

        var wo1 = workoutDao.insert(Workout(workoutName =  "Workout1"))
        var wo2 = workoutDao.insert(Workout(workoutName = "Workout2"))

        allDao = db.getAllDao()
        var ex6 = allDao.insert(Exercise(exerciseName = "Exercise6"))
        var ex7 = allDao.insert(Exercise(exerciseName = "Exercise7"))
        var wo3 = allDao.insert(Workout(workoutName = "Workout3"))
        var wo4 = allDao.insert(Workout(workoutName =  " Workout4"))
        var wo5 = allDao.insert(Workout(workoutName = "Workout5"))

        // Add 4 exercises to Workout1
        workoutExerciseMapDao.insert(WorkoutExerciseMap(wo1,ex7))
        allDao.insert(WorkoutExerciseMap(wo1,ex5))
        workoutExerciseMapDao.insert(WorkoutExerciseMap(wo1,ex3))
        workoutExerciseMapDao.insert(WorkoutExerciseMap(wo1,ex1))

        // Add 3 Exercises to Workout2
        allDao.insert(WorkoutExerciseMap(wo2,ex2))
        allDao.insert(WorkoutExerciseMap(wo2,ex4))
        allDao.insert(WorkoutExerciseMap(wo2,ex6))

        // Add 2 Exercises to Workout3
        workoutExerciseMapDao.insert(WorkoutExerciseMap(wo3,ex3))
        workoutExerciseMapDao.insert(WorkoutExerciseMap(wo3,ex4))

        // Add 1 Exercise to Workout 4
        allDao.insert(WorkoutExerciseMap(wo4,ex5))

        // Don't add anything to Workout 5

        for(wwe: WorkoutWithExercises in allDao.getAllWorkoutsWithExercises()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Workout is ${wwe.workout.workoutName}")
            for(ex: Exercise in wwe.exercises) {
                Log.d(TAG,"\tExercise is ${ex.exerciseName}")
            }
        }

        /* Show effect of onConflictStrategy.IGNORE */
        allDao.insert(Exercise(exerciseName = "Exercise1"))
        for(ex: Exercise in allDao.getAllExercises()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Exercise is ${ex.exerciseName}")
        }
        /* effect without onConflictStrategy.IGNORE i.e. exception
            i.e. exerciseDao does not have onConflictStrategy.IGNORE coded
         */
        exerciseDao.insert(Exercise(exerciseName = "Exercise1"))
        for(ex: Exercise in exerciseDao.getAllExercises()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Exercise is ${ex.exerciseName}")
        }
    }
}
```

- Note that the later code intentionally results in an exception to demonstrate the unique exercise name (index).

**Results**

When the above is run then the log includes :-

```
2021-08-07 10:17:07.368 D/WOEINFO: Workout is Workout1
2021-08-07 10:17:07.369 D/WOEINFO:  Exercise is Exercise1
2021-08-07 10:17:07.369 D/WOEINFO:  Exercise is Exercise3
2021-08-07 10:17:07.369 D/WOEINFO:  Exercise is Exercise5
2021-08-07 10:17:07.369 D/WOEINFO:  Exercise is Exercise7
2021-08-07 10:17:07.369 D/WOEINFO: Workout is Workout2
2021-08-07 10:17:07.369 D/WOEINFO:  Exercise is Exercise2
2021-08-07 10:17:07.369 D/WOEINFO:  Exercise is Exercise4
2021-08-07 10:17:07.369 D/WOEINFO:  Exercise is Exercise6
2021-08-07 10:17:07.369 D/WOEINFO: Workout is Workout3
2021-08-07 10:17:07.369 D/WOEINFO:  Exercise is Exercise3
2021-08-07 10:17:07.369 D/WOEINFO:  Exercise is Exercise4
2021-08-07 10:17:07.369 D/WOEINFO: Workout is  Workout4
2021-08-07 10:17:07.369 D/WOEINFO:  Exercise is Exercise5
2021-08-07 10:17:07.369 D/WOEINFO: Workout is Workout5
```

- i.e. the expected related data

After the first attempt to insert the duplicate exercise named "Exercise1" then :-

```
2021-08-07 10:17:07.376 D/WOEINFO: Exercise is Exercise1
2021-08-07 10:17:07.376 D/WOEINFO: Exercise is Exercise2
2021-08-07 10:17:07.376 D/WOEINFO: Exercise is Exercise3
2021-08-07 10:17:07.376 D/WOEINFO: Exercise is Exercise4
2021-08-07 10:17:07.376 D/WOEINFO: Exercise is Exercise5
2021-08-07 10:17:07.376 D/WOEINFO: Exercise is Exercise6
2021-08-07 10:17:07.377 D/WOEINFO: Exercise is Exercise7
```

- i.e. Exercise1 has not been duplicated

When the second attempt to insert an Exercise named "Exercise1" but using the insert from the ExerciseDao that does not have the onConflictStrategy.IGNORE then :-

```
2021-08-07 10:17:07.380 32394-32394/a.a.so68682797exerciseappexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: a.a.so68682797exerciseappexample, PID: 32394
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.a.so68682797exerciseappexample/a.a.so68682797exerciseappexample.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: Exercise.exerciseName (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few bullet points to clear up your confusions:

1. You can have one database for all entities.
2. Each entity should have separate repository.
3. DAO (Data Access Object) class is mainly for database operations (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).
4. You can create relation with one table to another via `@ForeignKey` annotation to the corresponding field.
5. You should not initialise database in Activity/viewModel. You should make a singleton class which will initiate the database in the `Application` class. That's how you initialise the database only when the app starts.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think I get it, but one thing I'm still confused about is whether or not should I have one DAO per database or one DAO per entity. And if its the latter, how do I query the relations and get the data. If for example I have a WorkoutWithExercises class, do I create a query in WorkoutDao or ExerciseDao, since the tutorial I'm following only uses one DAO I'm kinda lost

Comment: Or do I just create another Dao for that relation?

Comment: It's all about organising your things. You can query for any entity in any DAO.  It will increase your code readability if you write Workout related queries in a WorkOutDAO file. Other than that, it won't be a crime to write all queries in a single DAO